# Is a glvalue integral constant expression a constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constant-expression

N4527 5.20 [expr.const]p3

> An ***integral constant expression*** is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression.

5.20 [expr.const]p5

> A ***constant expression*** is either a glvalue core constant expression whose value refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose
>   value is an object where, for that object and its subobjects:
>
> (5.1) — each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant
>   expression, and
>
> (5.2) — if the object or subobject is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage
>   duration, the address past the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer
>   value.
>
> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an object with **static storage duration** that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or it is a
>   function.

```
void foo(){
    const int a = 1;//a has automatic storage duration
    // all ok in gcc 5.1.0 and clang 3.8.0
    int b[a]{};
    static_assert(a,"");
    switch(1){
      case a:
        ;
    }
}
```

Question1: Is `a` an **integral constant expression**?

Question2: Is `a` a **constant expression**?

Question3: Is a glvalue integral constant expression  a constant expression?

Question4:

If the answer of question 3 is yes, 
does this conflict with 5.20 p3 if the object has automatic storage duration?

Comment: Um one question per question please. One. Not five.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit The main question is 4, but if 3 is no, there's no necessary to ask 4, and so on. 1, 2, and 3 are part of 4.

Comment: `a` is a constant expression because of [expr.const]/(2.7.1).

Comment: @KerrekSB: Only if the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied.

Comment: @KerrekSB `a` is a **core constant expression** because of [expr.const]/(2.7.1).

Comment: Then reword it into a single question please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Does p5 conflict with p3 if the object has automatic storage duration?

Comment: @aschepler: Yes - it's hard to express that in syntax :-S

Comment: In your question! Not in a comment!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1, 2 and 3 are used to make sure people understand what i am asking. If you do, just skip them.

Comment: By your own quote, there's no such thing as a "glvalue integral constant expression", since an integral constant expression is, by definition, "an expression...implicitly converted to a prvalue".

Comment: @T.C. _integral constant expression is an expression_, and 3.10p1 _Every expression belongs to exactly one of the fundamental classifications in this taxonomy: lvalue, xvalue,
or prvalue._ So `const int a = 1;` expression `a` is an lvalue, if `a` is an integral constant expression, isn't this "glvalue integral constant expression"?

Comment: "An *integral constant expression* is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, ***implicitly converted to a prvalue***". The glvalue expression `a` is not an integral constant expression. The glvalue expression `a` implicitly converted to a prvalue is an integral constant expression.

Comment: According to these quotes, the expression `a` is: a prvalue core constant expression, and a glvalue, but not a glvalue core constant expression. This does seem like weird terminology.

Comment: @stackcpp: Don't call them "questions" then!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just one question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537359/const-int-a-1-is-a-a-constant-expression-if-a-has-automatic-storage-dura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is `a` an integral constant expression?

In the following contexts:

```
int b[a]{};
static_assert(a,"");
switch(1){
  case a:
    ;
}
```

yes, `a` is an integral constant expression. Starting with your first quote:

> An integral constant expression is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted
>   to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression.

'a' is an integral type, in your cases it will be implicitly converted to a prvalue, so now is `a` a core constant expression? Yes, if we go back to paragraph 2 which defines what is not a core constant expression:

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the
>   abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions

it has the following clause:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to

with the following exception:

> a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-volatile const
>   object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or

which applies to `a` since it is non-volatile, const and is initialized with a constant expression.

---

> Is `a` a constant expression?

In the same contexts as above, yes, since we can see from the quote above it is a core constant expression.

---

> Is a glvalue integral constant expression a constant expression?

No, in order for it to be a integral constant expression it must be converted to a prvalue and threfore can not be a glvalue.

Comment: @T.C.  @ Matt McNabb First, `a` is an id-expression, it is an lvalue expression, it is a core constant expression. Is it a integral constant expression?

Comment: @T.C.  said "The glvalue expression `a` is not an integral constant expression." and @Shafik Yaghmour said "Yes".

Comment: Core constant expression before converted is integral constant expression, or after converted is integral constant expression?

Comment: @stackcpp so these are all in context of certain expressions, so a constant expression is a `conditional-expression` and so you are looking for places in the grammar where `conditional-expression` or `constant-expression` show up.

Comment: My original thought is `const int a = 1;//a has automatic storage duration`, and according to 5.20p5, in constant expression, an object to which glvalue core constant expression refers must have static storage duration. So `a` is not  constant expression, but it can be used as array boundary, so it is a integral constant expression. This is weird. A integral constant expression is not a constant expression. There must be wrong somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537359/const-int-a-1-is-a-a-constant-expression-if-a-has-automatic-storage-du

Comment: I think `a` is a lvalue core constant expression. Because `a` has automatic storage duration, so `a` is not a constant expression. But after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, there will be a constant expression.

Comment: Or in context of `int b[a]{};`, 'a' is a constant expression. But in in context of `int &b = a;`, 'a` is not a constant expression.

Comment: @stackcpp that is what I said :-) let me look at rewording it, not sure how long that will take.

Comment: @stackcpp the new question is very similar to this one, you should at least indicate that it is a clarification of this question although I am going to guess some would consider them duplicates.