# Declaring array with const and constexpr

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

While investigating the constexpr keyword in C++, I've come up with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int n  = 10;
    constexpr int n2 = 10;

    int a1[n];
    int a2[n2];

    std::cout << "n " << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << "n2 " << n2 << std::endl;
}
```

I would expect that declaring the array a1 with "const" would not work and the compiler would at least give me a warning (assuming the compilation is done with g++ -Wall -pedantic constexpr_1.cpp -o ce1) but it does not. I've seen some error with VS compiler so any hint is welcome here.

Comment: The size of an array must be known at compile time and both `n` and `n2` are known at compile time and can't be modified at runtime, at least not in a legal way. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346879/const-vs-constexpr-on-variables) is interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the size of each array dimension in an array declaration must be an [integral constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

A *constant expression* (with some exceptions) is a value that can be evaluated at compile-time. That includes `const` variables with automatic storage duration initialized by a constant expression [[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537359/const-int-a-1-is-a-a-constant-expression-if-a-has-automatic-storage-du).

Therefore both `const int n  = 10;` and `constexpr int n2 = 10;` are usable as a size in array declarations and the code example is valid.

Note: this is not the case in C - so make sure to compile in C++ mode [[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902512/why-the-size-of-array-as-a-constant-variable-is-not-allowed-in-c-but-allowed-in).

The code also compiles fine in MSVC 2015+. But it could very well be that an archaic VC++ compiler has a bug that prevents this from compiling.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. I've been confused by this article: https://smartbear.com/blog/develop/using-constexpr-to-improve-security-performance-an/ which states that the compiler should warn something like: //compilation error: “constant expression required”.