# Using argc in a constexpr, is it strictly required that any sub-expression involved be a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer, constexpr

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char**)
{
    constexpr int a = argc * 0;
    (void)a;
    constexpr int b = argc - argc;
    (void)b;
    return 0;
}
```

`argc` is not a constant expression, but the compiler is still able to compute the results of `a` and `b` in compile time (i.e. `0`) in both cases.

[g++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Q0CpJqBPuPiT5nTa) accepts the code above, while [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Y3kelmH0N6fyuw6Y) and MSVC14 reject it.

Does the standard allows the compiler being as smart as g++ with regard to `constexpr`?

Comment: I think both of these should be rejected due to [expr.const]/2: `argc` is not a core constant expression because it involves lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of a variable that wasn't initialized with a constant expression.

Comment: Now that I had a chance to think about it this looks similar to [int a=1, is a || 1 a constant expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31526278/1708801)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither `argc * 0` nor `argc - argc` are constant expressions, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is allowed in certain cases none of them apply here. If we look at the draft C++11 standard section `5.19` [expr.const] it lays out the exceptions. It says:

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it involves one of the following as a potentially
>   evaluated subexpression [...]

and has several bullets including the following on lvalue-to-rvalue conversion:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
> - a glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding
>     initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or
> - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr, or that refers
>     to a sub-object of such an object, or
> - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile temporary object whose lifetime has not
>     ended, initialized with a constant expression;

It is interesting to note that gcc does not accept the following code (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/96yJb9xdM83Iujls)*):

```
constexpr int a = argc * 2;
```

So it looks like gcc is saying I know the result will be zero and therefore it performs constant folding and it does not need to perform the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `argc` to determine the result.

Unfortunately I don't see any provisions in section `5.19` that allows this kind of short-circuiting. This looks very similar to case in [int a=1, is a || 1 a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31526278/1708801) which has a bug report but no one from the gcc team has replied to that one. I added a [comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55986#c5) to that bug report indicating this seems related.

Mark's comment below indicates this is a bug:

> There is a whole c++-delayed-folding branch on which some gcc developers are working, which will delay a number of optimizations and might fix this. It is important for other reasons, rejecting the code in this question is very low priority

Do constant expressions strictly require every sub-expression to be a constant expression? No, for example from `5.19` it says: (*emphasis mine*)

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it involves one of the following as a potentially
>   evaluated subexpression (3.2), **but subexpressions of logical AND (5.14), logical OR (5.15), and conditional
>   (5.16) operations that are not evaluated are not considered** [...]

So the following is a constant expression:

```
constexpr int a = false && argc * 0;
```

Because `argc * 0` is not evaluated since `&&` evaluates left-to-right and short-circuits.

Comment: There is a whole c++-delayed-folding branch on which some gcc developers are working, which will delay a number of optimizations and might fix this. It is important for other reasons, rejecting the code in this question is very low priority.

Comment: @downvote please explain what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: @MarcGlisse thank you for the information, I can not think of a lot of scenarios where this would lead a serious issue, aside from portability type issues. Are there any mailings you could point me to, I am curious to understand the issue better.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I guess [this other issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31526278/1708801) is due to the same cause?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here:
[constexpr at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

The baseline is that a constexpr should be something that can be determined unambiguously at compile-time so that the compiler can substitute its value in the expression is evaluated.

I think the problem is the argc is not a constexpr. Is not something the compiler knows. In fact you can execute your main with a different number of arguments. If gcc accepts it it may be a bug or there may be some subtle thing involved I don't get.

Comment: "something that can be determined unambiguously at compile-time", both `a` and `b` can be determined at compile time.

Comment: @zenith unfortunately the rules do not allow for bypassing the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of `argc` and therefore it makes it a non-constant expression.