# Why the expression strlen(cstr1) did not evaluate to a constant, where cstr1 is a const char array?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

The compiler says that expression did not evaluate to a constant when I build the following code. But I don't know how to fix the error. Can anybody help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const char cstr1[] = "Hello";
const char cstr2[] = "world!";

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t new_size = strlen(cstr1) + strlen(" ") + strlen(cstr2) + 1;
    char cstr3[new_size];

    strcpy(cstr3, cstr1);
    strcat(cstr3, " ");
    strcat(cstr3, cstr2);

    std::cout << cstr3 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Works fine http://ideone.com/JbzGH8

Comment: If you're using `g++` did you forget to use `--std=c++0x`

Comment: @AndyBrown that flag applied before 2011, now it is `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`

Comment: Just use `std::string`!

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 is used when I compile the code. I'am reading C++ primer (the fifth edition). This problem happened when I am doing Exercise 3.40.

Comment: @HappyCoder put const char cstr1[] = "Hello"; const char cstr2[] = "world!"; in main function, will run error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `strlen` is not declared `constexpr`, so the result of it cannot be used in a `constexpr`.

You could try and get around this by using `sizeof`, but really you shouldn't be using C-style strings in the first place. C++ has `std::string` for a reason:

```
const std::string str1 = "Hello";
const std::string str2 = "world!";

int main(){
    std::string str3 = str1 + ' ' + str2;

    std::cout << str3 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Further info for those who are confused by g++ accepting OP's code: g++ [is buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744079/is-it-a-conforming-compiler-extension-to-treat-non-constexpr-standard-library-fu) and treats the result of some standard library functions as `constexpr` when in fact they are not, and the Standard explicitly forbids compilers from doing this

Comment: Thank you for the info @M.M

Answer (score 1):

The standard says that `strlen` is a genuine function, and isn't known to the compiler what it does, and it's not a `constexpr` type function (after all, it's exactly the same function being called if you use `fgets` to read the input from a file or terminal).

Many modern compilers DO understand what `strlen` does, so the compiler will optimize away the call to the function and replace it with a constant in this type of case. However, it's not required to behave this way in the standard, so whether it works in a particular compiler is entirely up to that particular compiler (and possibly compiler options that enable some type of optimisation!)

Comment: It is known to the compiler exactly what `strlen` does: The C++ standard specifies its behaviour.  However that is not relevant; what is relevant is that it is not declared `constexpr`.

Comment: The C++ standard does not actually specify the behaviour of `strlen()`.  It simply says it is declared in `cstring` and otherwise refers to the C standard.   In any event, being specified in the C++ standard is not the same as "known to the compiler".   Whether the compiler is built with specific handling/optimisation of functions like `strlen()` is a quality of implementation concern, not a requirement of the standards.

Comment: Nobody said anything about "specific handling/optimization". The effect of `strlen` is to return the number of characters in the string and the compiler knows this. I guess you are thinking something like "the compiler doesn't look in the glibc code" but that doesn't matter at all, C++ is defined in terms of observable behaviour.

Comment: I _know_ that both gcc and clang (and probably MS compilers) can translate `strlen` from a constant string to a constant. However, the standard does not require this to happen, since `strlen` CAN also be used for non-constant strings, making it a non-constant value.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` is a function that is evaluated at run time, not compile time.  Hence the error message.  It is inherited from C, so not declared `constexpr` (which is specific to later versions of C++).

Better to avoid using `<cstring>` - and arrays of `char` for that matter - and use the `std::string` type declared in `<string>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string cstr1 = "Hello";
const std::string cstr2 = "world!";

int main()
{
    std::string cstr3 = cstr1 + std::string(" ") + cstr2;
    std::cout << cstr3 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `constexpr` integers are integer constant expressions, so `char cstr3[new_size];` is not a VLA. That part of the code is correct.