# Constexpr compile error using std::acos with clang++ not g++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++14, constexpr, clang++

I want to experiment with migrating a project from gcc to clang++. I admit ignorance on my part, I'm not sure why the following bit of code

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T pi{std::acos(T(-1.0))};
```

compiles silently with g++ but clang++ produces the error

```
trig.hpp:3:13: error: constexpr variable 'pi<float>' must be initialized by a constant expression
constexpr T pi{std::acos(T(-1.0))};
```

and I was hoping someone who knows more about it than I do could enlighten me.

NB: Tried with -std=C++14 and C++1y. Fails under clang version 3.6.2 (tags/RELEASE_362/final). Works with g++ (GCC) 5.2.0.

Comment: Looks related to [Is it a conforming compiler extension to treat non-constexpr standard library functions as constexpr?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27744079/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I thought I searched well. I was wrong. Thank you. This is a disappointing result indeed. I'm also surprised that GCC doesn't at least emit a warning when it's going to allow something forbidden in the standard. I was compiling with -pedantic too!

If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am not surprised that question did not come up, the overlap in keywords seems minimal. When I first ran into this about a year ago I could not find anything and it was not until I accidentally ran into the language working group issue 2013 when I managed to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clang is correct here, we are not allowed to use `acos` in a constant expression.

The issue is that [acos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/acos) is not marked constexpr in the standard but [gcc treats some functions not marked in the standard including acos as constexpr](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49813). This is a [non-conforming extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27744079/1708801) and should eventually be fixed in gcc.

[Builtin functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) are often used to constant fold and we can see if we use `-fno-builtin` with gcc it disables this non-conforming behavior and we will receive the following error:

```
error: call to non-constexpr function 'double acos(double)'
constexpr T pi{std::acos(T(-1.0))};
                         ^
```