# A function call must have a constant value in a constant expression

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have written a c++ program as blow:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    constexpr double a = 4.0;
    constexpr double b = sqrt(a);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile this code with visual studio 2017, I got an error that says a function call must have a constant value in a constant expression. The bad line is "constexpr double b = sqrt(a);".

But when I used g++ to compile the same code, no error was reported.

What's the reason of the error? What's the different between g++ and vc++?

Comment: Maybe this. VS doesn't claim to properly support `constexpr` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx.

Comment: What `sqrt` are you calling? `std::sqrt` doesn't appear to be required to be a `constexpr` function.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744079/is-it-a-conforming-compiler-extension-to-treat-non-constexpr-standard-library-fu

Answer (score 5):

`sqrt` isn't a `constexpr` function so can't be used in a `constexpr` expression. GCC seems to have a special built in version of `sqrt` which is `constexpr`. Clang doesn't allow this code either:

https://godbolt.org/z/SvFEAW

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt` is required to be not a constant expression so `constexpr double b = sqrt(a);` is not supposed to work. [Clang does not build this code as well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cYSfassyPBGnVFME). You also need to include `<cmath>` header in order to use this function.

Answer (score -2):

```
  include cmath library since you using a sqrt() function
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/