# unexpected constexpr availability of std::sqrt, std::hypot etc in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, constexpr

`std::sqrt` (and similarly `std::hypot` and other `<cmaths>` functions) are not (yet) constexpr.

So, basically why does this work in gcc?

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    static constexpr double root2 = std::sqrt(10);
    static constexpr int int_root2 = static_cast<int>(root2);
    static_assert(int_root2 == 3);
    return int_root2;
}
```

Works in gcc, but not in clang, which throws the expected

```
error: constexpr variable 'root2' must be initialized by a constant expression
    static constexpr double root2 = std::sqrt(10);
```

[Godbolt comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/6vjz6W6E8)

Simply: gcc functionality that is outside (beyond) the standard and can't be relied upon?

**Update**:

From the comments below:

if we pass `-fno-builtin` to gcc and change the argument to `std:sqrt` to `10.0` then gcc throws an error, because its builtin for ints is constexpr. [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744079/is-it-a-conforming-compiler-extension-to-treat-non-constexpr-standard-library-fu)

Comment: You could try other compile options, like `-pedantic`, and see if it complains.

Comment: @FredLarson still works with `-pedantic` : https://godbolt.org/z/7T3YdWe7x

Comment: GCC is not conforming to the standard on this. It is a known issue. There probably is a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: @OliverSchönrock: Yeah, I tried it too. Same result. It was worth a shot!

Comment: @user17732522 what do you mean by "duplicate"? A duplicate SO Q?

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Yes, I am going to look for one.

Comment: Maybe this one?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744079/is-it-a-conforming-compiler-extension-to-treat-non-constexpr-standard-library-fu

Comment: @user17732522 But is it `libstd++` or is it the compiler? On my machine I am compiling against `libstdc++` with both gcc and clang. gcc tolerates it and clang doesn't. Godbolt does the same by default I believe.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Yes, I realized that it is GCC specifically.

Comment: @user17732522
That other SO Q is good. But if I pass `-fno-builtin` as suggested there... IT STILL WORKS

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Yes, good point. It seems the overloads with integral type parameters are not affected by `-fno-builtin`. I suppose asking about that specifically might make a good non-duplicate question.

Comment: libstdc++ explicitly uses __builtin_sqrt in the overload that takes an int. If you try `std::sqrt(10.)`, -fno-builtin will matter.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Check. So gcc is just non-conforming and has been for at least 7 years, and is obviously not intending to fix it...

Comment: It seems likely the standard will eventually make those functions constexpr. Spending time to write a patch to reject this code feels like a waste of time when there are so many more useful things to improve in gcc.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yeah.. it fails "as-if" that's all

Comment: Is it non conforming or does it fall under implementation specific functionality?

Comment: @Taekahn I am not really qualified to answer that, but the above-linked potential duplicate makes the case that it is non-conforming, I think.